# .htaccess for directory and subdirectory levels

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect to diferents files when the URL have 1 directory or 2 subdirectories.

http://example.com/content/category-1/
http://example.com/content/category-2/
http://example.com/content/category-3/
This will execute "category.php"

http://example.com/content/category-1/subcategory-5/
http://example.com/content/category-2/subcategory-21/
http://example.com/content/category-3/subcategory-88/
This will execute "subcategory.php"

Using next code on .htaccess the first option is working, but I need the other Condition to work the second.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /content/(.*)(/*)
RewriteRule (.*) /category.php?id=$1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What value do you need to pass in the `id` URL parameter? Where is the `.htaccess` file located? You've not included this in your question description, only in the code (which actually looks incorrect). You also don't appear to have attempted to implement the second case with 2 subdirectories?

Comment: the ID parameter will be for example the URL without domain. Then the php file will manage to extract the ID.

htaccess is located in root directory, when is the index.php too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You will have to replicate the last rewrite rule again further matching the next subcategory values if available.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /subcategory.php?id=$1&subcat=$2 [L,NC,NE,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?content/([^/]+)/?$ /category.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: The `RewriteCond` directives on the 2nd and 3rd rules would seem to be entirely superfluous.

Comment: @MrWhite Can you elaborate?

Comment: You are already performing the necessary URL comparison with the `RewriteRule` _pattern_, with which you are also capturing the backreferences. The preceding _condition_ simply repeats the same (in fact, _less specific_) check. The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is processed first, so the preceding condition is not required - it's repeating the same check so results in "twice" the work.

Comment: @MrWhite Nice catch, removed the redundant ones.